# How to get a value from textarea within modal popup? and how to show the value in my input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a text field, if I click on the text field a modal popup shows up with a text field "Enter here". Now if enter some text there and click 
'ok', the text should be shown in the first text input field.

I tried but its not working. Here is my failed fiddle..

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/wfktnd25/)**

```html
<!-- Input field -->
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Enter here" class="form-control" name="address" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" />

<!-- text popup modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="narratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="myModalLabel">Narration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="modal_note">Note: Only alphabets A-Z a-z number 0-9 and characters % [] () - _ . , are allowed in text</label>
        <textarea class="cash_text">
                                                                Enter Here...
                                                            </textarea>
        <span class="modal_valid">0/200 Characterts entered</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the Javascript in your failed fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Javascript. Add an `id` to the button and to the textarea. And then display the value of the textarea in the input, when the button is clicked. For example:

```js
document.getElementById('ok_button').addEventListener('click', function () {
document.getElementById('address').value = document.getElementById('cash_text').value
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Enter here" class="form-control" name="address" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" />

<div class="modal fade" id="narratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="myModalLabel">Narration</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label class="modal_note">Note: Only alphabets A-Z a-z number 0-9 and characters % [] () - _ . , are allowed in text</label>
            <textarea id="cash_text" class="cash_text">Enter Here...</textarea>
            <span class="modal_valid">0/200 Characterts entered</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
            <button id="ok_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```